# Counter(Time left) in Recyclerview android

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-recyclerview, counter

I have a `recyclerview` that has `circleprogreesbar` that shows time left to commplete the survey .

meeting start time = 1 pm
meeting end time = 2 pm

survey active from = 2 pm to 3 pm  (only for 1 hour)

**my logic**
 time left =  survey end time - current time

My counter is not dynamically updating the

MeetingSurveryAdapter.java

```
public class MeetingSurveryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MeetingSurveryAdapter.SurveyViewHolder> {

        private static final String TAG = "SurveryAdapter";

        private List<MeetingSurveyModel> list;
        MeetingSurveyModel model;
        private Context mContext;
        private int mSize;
        private UtilMethods utilMethods;
        private AppCompatActivity activity;

        private int mPreviousPosition;

        // Adapters
        private ArrayAdapter<String> adapterCountry;

        private final List<SurveyViewHolder> lstHolders;

        private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
        private Runnable updateRemainingTimeRunnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                        synchronized (lstHolders) {
                                long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                for (SurveyViewHolder holder : lstHolders) {
                                        holder.updateTimeRemaining(currentTime);
                                }
                        }
                }
        };


        public MeetingSurveryAdapter(Context mContext, List<MeetingSurveyModel> list) {
                this.list = list;
                this.mContext = mContext;
                this.activity = (AppCompatActivity) mContext;
                utilMethods = new UtilMethods(mContext);
                lstHolders = new ArrayList<>();
                startUpdateTimer();
        }

        @Override
        public SurveyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

                View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_meeting_survey, viewGroup, false);
                SurveyViewHolder viewHolder = new SurveyViewHolder(view);
                return viewHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final SurveyViewHolder surveyViewHolder, final int position) {

                model = list.get(position);
                surveyViewHolder.tvTitle.setText(model.Title);
                surveyViewHolder.tvDate.setText(utilMethods.formatDateMeetingSurvey(model.MeetingDate));
                surveyViewHolder.tvParticipantsCount.setText("Participants: " + model.Participants);

                surveyViewHolder.setData(list.get(position));
                synchronized (lstHolders) {
                        lstHolders.add(surveyViewHolder);
                }
                surveyViewHolder.updateTimeRemaining(System.currentTimeMillis());

                surveyViewHolder.relativeTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                openMettingSurveyList(surveyViewHolder, position);
                        }
                });

                if (position > mPreviousPosition) {
                        animate1(surveyViewHolder, true);
                } else {
                        animate1(surveyViewHolder, false);
                }
                mPreviousPosition = position;
        }

        private void openMettingSurveyList(SurveyViewHolder surveyViewHolder, int position) {
                MeetingSurveyModel model = list.get(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MeetingSurveyDetailsActivity.class);
                activity.startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
                return list.size();
        }

        public class SurveyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

                @Bind(R.id.relative_title)
                RelativeLayout relativeTitle;
                @Bind(R.id.img_number3)
                ImageView imgNumber3;
                @Bind(R.id.tv_title)
                TextView tvTitle;
                @Bind(R.id.tv_date)
                TextView tvDate;
                @Bind(R.id.tv_participants_count)
                TextView tvParticipantsCount;
                @Bind(R.id.prg_counter)
                DonutProgress prgCounter;
                @Bind(R.id.tv_counter)
                TextView tvCounter;


                public void setData(MeetingSurveyModel item) {
                        model = item;
                        //prgCounter.setSuffixText(item.Status);
                        updateTimeRemaining(System.currentTimeMillis());
                }

                public void updateTimeRemaining(long currentTime) {
                        long timeDiff = utilMethods.getLongDate(model.MeetingDeadLine) - currentTime;
                        if (timeDiff > 0) {
                                int minutes= Integer.parseInt(String.format("%d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(timeDiff) ));
                                prgCounter.setProgress(prgCounter.getProgress() + minutes);
                                //prgCounter.setSuffixText(""+minutes);
                        } else {
                                list.remove(getLayoutPosition());
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                                tvCounter.setText("Expired!!");
                                //prgCounter.setSuffixText("0");
                        }
                }

                public SurveyViewHolder(View itemView) {
                        super(itemView);
                        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
                        prgCounter.setTextSize(18);
                        prgCounter.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                }

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                        switch (view.getId()) {
                        }
                }
        }

        private void startUpdateTimer() {
                Timer tmr = new Timer();
                tmr.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                                mHandler.post(updateRemainingTimeRunnable);
                        }
                }, 1000, 1000);
        }

        public void animate1(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, boolean goesDown) {
                int holderHeight = holder.itemView.getHeight();
                holder.itemView.setPivotY(goesDown == true ? 0 : holderHeight);

                AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
                ObjectAnimator animatorTranslateY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.itemView, "translationY", goesDown == true ? 200 : 0, 0);
                animatorTranslateY.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());

                animatorTranslateY.setDuration(700);
                animatorTranslateY.start();
        }
}
```

my expectation :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try use instead of

```
       private void startUpdateTimer() {
                Timer tmr = new Timer();
                tmr.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                                mHandler.post(updateRemainingTimeRunnable);
                        }
                }, 1000, 1000);
        }
```

this

```
        private Runnable updateRemainingTimeRunnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                        synchronized (lstHolders) {
                                long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                for (SurveyViewHolder holder : lstHolders) {
                                        holder.updateTimeRemaining(currentTime);
                                }
                        }
                        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                }
        };
        ......
        private void startUpdateTimer() {
             mHandler.postDelayed(updateRemainingTimeRunnable,1000);
        }
```

It seems like this runnable runs only ones

Or there're one more solution:
Call adapter.notifyDataSetChange every 1000 ms in your activity or fragment, and calculate time left inside onBindViewHolder depending on current time